# How can I dynamically import packages in Java?

Tags: java, package

Imagine that I have a program that needs to import some package. But the package can be implemented by different people. How can I compile my code with different packages, without changing my code each time?

Thanks

Comment: not clear what are you asking ?

Comment: you should define an interface that would not change... (but the implementation can change und can replace existing code)

Comment: Yea, that is the best. My problem is I my code uses the code generated by Google Protocol Buffer. I don't want to change the generated code.

Comment: isn't the generated coded depending on your protokol definition (the proto-file)? if you don't change that, then you'll always generate the same code

Comment: Please post an example of the problem you are facing.

Comment: I am writing a library. Users of the library must write their own proto file and generate java files. Then my library use their generated java file